# Cache evict behavior when method throws exception

Tags: spring-boot, caching

What is the behavior of `CacheEvict` when the exception is thrown in the following method? Will it clear the entries anyway?

```java
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
public void deleteById(int id) {
    if (!this.repository.existsById(id)) {
        throw new Exception("Resource not found.");
    }

    this.repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

In another words, I want to `CacheEvict` only if no exception occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in documentation of [`@CacheEvict`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html), more specifically in the [`beforeInvocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#beforeInvocation()) argument.

> Setting this attribute to `true`, causes the eviction to occur irrespective of the method outcome (i.e., whether it threw an exception or not).
>
> Defaults to `false`, meaning that the cache eviction operation will occur after the advised method is invoked successfully (i.e. only if the invocation did not throw an exception).

So by default it will only evict when no exception occurs.